# Sorting a struct array isn't working as I expect it to work

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, struct

I'm having trouble with sorting struct's.

I have a struct of cars with info like Brand ('Marke'), Model ('Modelis') and Price ('Kaina').
When a user enters this brand, model and price the program is supposed to sort those arrays based on the price from smallest to biggest and print out only sorted array's `char brand` and `char model`.

I first tested my sorting script with 10 arrays - works just as it should.
Then I tested it with 3 arrays that have have prices arranged like this: `'200' '300' '100'` - works as well.
But as soon as user inputs prices in a descending way like: `'300' '200' '100'` - it doesn't sort the right way and what I get is: `'100' '300' '200'`. Here is the whole script:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Automobiliai {

    char Marke[20];
    char Modelis[20];
    float Kaina;

};

struct Automobiliai Prijungti(char *_marke, char *_modelis){

    struct Automobiliai p;
    strcpy(p.Marke, _marke);
    strcpy(p.Modelis, _modelis);

    return p;

};

int main()
{

    struct Automobiliai automobilis[3];

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){

        printf("%d automobilis: Marke Modelis Kaina \n", i+1);
        scanf("%s %s %f", automobilis[i].Marke, automobilis[i].Modelis, &automobilis[i].Kaina);

    }

    struct Automobiliai _automobilis[3];

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){

        for(int j = i + 1; j < 3; j++){

            if(automobilis[i].Kaina > automobilis[j].Kaina){

                _automobilis[i] = Prijungti(automobilis[i].Marke, automobilis[i].Modelis);
                automobilis[i] = Prijungti(automobilis[j].Marke, automobilis[j].Modelis);
                automobilis[j] = Prijungti(_automobilis[i].Marke, _automobilis[i].Modelis);

            }

        }

    }

    printf("Automobiliu markes modelio kainos atzvilgiu tvarka: \n");
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){

        printf("%s %s\n", automobilis[i].Marke, automobilis[i].Modelis);

    }

}
```

To be a little more specific this is the part of the code I'm having trouble with:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){

        for(int j = i + 1; j < 3; j++){

            if(automobilis[i].Kaina > automobilis[j].Kaina){

                _automobilis[i] = Prijungti(automobilis[i].Marke, automobilis[i].Modelis);
                automobilis[i] = Prijungti(automobilis[j].Marke, automobilis[j].Modelis);
                automobilis[j] = Prijungti(_automobilis[i].Marke, _automobilis[i].Modelis);

            }

        }

    }
```

I can image why this is happening and I think I should add one more condition to my `if` but my head hurts already and I can't think far beyond than making a variable just before the loop's: `int a = 0;` and remaking the loop's like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){

        for(int j = i + 1; j < 3; j++){

            if(automobilis[i].Kaina > a){

                a = automobilis[j].Kaina;
                _automobilis[i] = Prijungti(automobilis[i].Marke, automobilis[i].Modelis);
                automobilis[i] = Prijungti(automobilis[j].Marke, automobilis[j].Modelis);
                automobilis[j] = Prijungti(_automobilis[i].Marke, _automobilis[i].Modelis);

            }

        }

    }
```

Yet it doesn't solve this.

Comment: Please take a look at bubble sort algorithm, follow this link https://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/source-code/c-program-bubble-sort (PD: it was the first result I got from google). There are more efficient sorting algortihms

Comment: @Nestor The result is the same for me. Actually the method from that link is more or less the same as mine only its more complicated if you ask me.

Comment: The function `Prijungti` is creating and returning a new struct, but one of its three members (`Kaina`) is uninitialized. Is this intended?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel oh? which one? if you're talking about ```struct Automobiliai p;``` then without it ```char Marke[20];``` etc. wouldn't work am I right?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Yeah. This is one of the homework assignments where in the end the program is supposed to print out only the brand and the model. Price is just to use it to sort them in a line so to say. I've created this 'function' just so I could call it out in the ```if``` statement writing 3 lines of code instead of minimum 9. Less code is better and less complicated am I right?

Comment: @AleksandrasVištorskij: The function `Prijungti` is creating a new `struct Automobiliai p` and setting its member `p.Marke` and `p.Modelis`, but it is not setting `p.Kaina`. Therefore, the returned struct will have an indeterminate ("garbage") value in the member variable `Kaina`. Consequently, the line `automobilis[i] = Prijungti(automobilis[j].Marke, automobilis[j].Modelis);` will set `automobilis[i].Kaina` to an indeterminate value. When you next check that value in the line `if(automobilis[i].Kaina > a){`, you will be comparing with an indeterminate value. This cannot be correct.

Comment: @AleksandrasVištorskij: If you don't use `Kaina` afterwards, but only use `Marke` and `Modelis`, then it may be acceptable to leave `Kaina` uninitialized. But in your case, you are accessing `automobilis[i] ` up to three times per outer loop iteration (depending on how many times the `if` statement is true). Therefore, setting it to an indeterminate value should not be done, unless you are sure that you won't access it afterwards. As far as I can tell, you cannot be sure of this.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Appreciate it! And yeah I'm sure I won't access it afterwards. The work is supposed end after it's sorted and printed out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225745/discussion-between-andreas-wenzel-and-aleksandras-vistorskij).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just use a temporary variable to put on increasing order like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Automobiliai
{
    char Marke[20];
    char Modelis[20];
    float Kaina;
}Automobiliai;

int main()
{
    Automobiliai automobilis[3];

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("%d automobilis: Marke Modelis Kaina \n", i+1);
        scanf("%s %s %f", automobilis[i].Marke, automobilis[i].Modelis, &automobilis[i].Kaina);
    }
    
    Automobiliai temp;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if(automobilis[i].Kaina > automobilis[j].Kaina)
            {
                temp = automobilis[j];
                automobilis[j]=automobilis[i];
                automobilis[i]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Automobiliu markes modelio kainos atzvilgiu tvarka: \n");
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("%s %s\n", automobilis[i].Marke, automobilis[i].Modelis);
    }
}
```

Comment: YES! This is it and it works and yet that's how I was first trying to make this loop but It didn't work. Could you explain a little bit on what difference does ```typedef``` make for this struct? I know I get an error without it typing ```}Automobiliai;``` and just before the loop's ```Automobiliai temp;``` but why?

Comment: @AleksandrasVištorskij: Using the `typedef` allows you to write `Automobiliai` instead of having to write `struct Automobiliai` all the time. It is not required, it is just a convenience. You don't need to use the `typedef` to get your code to work. You can continue writing `struct Automobiliai` everywhere instead, if you wish.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Riiiiight! Obviously. Thank you!

Comment: The typedef means you no longer have to write struct Automobiliai all over the place. That not only saves keystrokes, it also can make the code cleaner since it provides a smidgen more abstraction.